# Make an activity the default activity as soon as it is started for the first time

Tags: java, android

I have written an Android application that checks if a string entered in the EditText is the same as the one stored in the shared preferences if it's wrong, a Toast appears telling the user that the string he just entered is incorrect and this is true a new activity is open. I would like this open activity to be opened every time the user opens the application.

Here is what I try:

```java
private PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper;
private ParseContent parseContent;
private final int RegTask = 1;
private EditText editText;
private Button button;
private String string;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login2);

    parseContent = new ParseContent(this);
    preferenceHelper = new PreferenceHelper(this);

    editText = findViewById(R.id.code);
    button = findViewById(R.id.abonnement);

    final SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            string = editText.getText().toString();
            if (string.equals(pref.getString("code", null))){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Désolé mais votre code est incorrect",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When the user enters the correct code, ie the previously registered code in the preference shared, `WelcomeActivty.class` opens but when the user exits the application and enters again, `Login.class` is always displayed while I would like `WelcomeActivity.class` to be launched every time the user enters the application again....How can I do this please ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** I made a login system (without password), even if you are not working on a login system, I still think this technique can still apply in your case.

Try to add another sharedpreference that stores a boolean value to check whether the user is online or not. For instance, in your LoginActivity, add

> editor.putBoolean("isOnline", true); editor.apply();

when you click the login button.

Similarly, when you logout, just put

> editor.putBoolean("isOnline", false); editor.apply();

This is how I did according to your issues.

MainActivity.java (This is the login activity)

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText et = findViewById(R.id.et);
        Button btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
        Button btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);



        pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = pref.edit();

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                editor.putString("username", et.getText().toString());
                editor.putBoolean("isOnline", false);
                editor.apply();
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (et.getText().toString().equals(pref.getString("username", null))) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name", et.getText().toString());
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    editor.putBoolean("isOnline", true);
                    editor.apply();

                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrect input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

// This is when user has not clicked the log out button, then we go to the WelcomeActivity instead
        if (pref.getBoolean("isOnline", false)) {

            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

WelcomeActivity.java (the activity we visit after login)

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);


        pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = pref.edit();

        editor.putBoolean("isOnline", true);
        editor.apply();

        Button btnLogout = findViewById(R.id.logout);
        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // When user clicks on the logout button, we set this to false. So everything will be back to normal.
                editor.putBoolean("isOnline", false);
                editor.apply();

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finishAffinity();
                }
                else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work, every time I open the application is still Login.class that appears

Comment: Have you tried copy and paste this code to see how it works in the first place?

Comment: I would recommend that you try this code in another project and have 2 activities (MainActivity and WelcomeActivity). Then, try to add 1 EditText and 2 buttons in MainActivity.java and 1 button in WelcomeActivity.java. If you do that, I am sure you will have the definite clue whether this works or not.

Comment: I did exactly what you said and it worked... Thank!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your logic, when you open the app Login.class will be your first screen, in that screen you have to check that is entered code is similar to shared preference value and if it is true then move login screen to welcome screen, I hope my answer is fruitful for you

Comment: What do you mean by "Move" the login screen?

Answer (score 1):

Mate, this can be done by creating a session.

Like when your edit text matches with your desired text you should assign a value in the shared preference which will act as your session is created.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 string = editText.getText().toString();
 if (string.equals(pref.getString("code", null))){
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
    edit.putString("Session", "1");
    edit.apply();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(intent);
}else {
  Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Désolé mais votre code est incorrect",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Now in your onCreate method of your desired screen. Just check whether the session value is contained in your SharedPreferences and do whatever according to your need.

Happy Coding

Comment: If I use this code for example as you indicate and I check the value of the session in the `WelcomeActivity.class` onCreate if the value is true, what code should I write at this level for the application to open directly `WelcomeActivitty.class` without going through `Login.class`

Comment: Do you have a splash activity or something ?

Answer (score 1):

Save the entered value in shared preference also use "EncryptedSharedPreferences" for security then

on the onCreate check if the user entered the value and saved before put your checking

```
if (string.equals(pref.getString("code", null))){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      startActivity(intent);`enter code here`
}
```

and finish current activity
So now automatically next screen will open

Comment: excuse me but I do not quite understand what you ask me to do!